# Sqlite foreign key insert should fail

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite

Why is Sqlite allowing me to insert a foreign key in table2 that does not match with any primary keys in table1?
I am using .NET and System.Data.SQLite.dll

Here is my setup:

```
create table [table1] (
  [Id] integer primary key NOT NULL
, [col1] nvarchar(100)  NULL
);

create table [table2] (
  [Id] integer primary key NOT NULL
, [col2] integer  NOT NULL
, FOREIGN KEY(col2) REFERENCES table1(Id)
);

INSERT INTO [table1] ([col1]) VALUES ('val1');
INSERT INTO [table2] ([col2]) VALUES ('2');
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/4fccc/1/0

Comment: Seems like a duplication, although i solved it with enabling the foreign key constraints in the connection string like so: "Data Source=:memory:;foreign keys=true;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the foreign key constraints in the connection string like so: "Data Source=:memory:;foreign keys=true;"